# How to set and re-set dropify default image using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, laravel-blade, dropify

I have a datatable that has multiple columns and 1 column containing images, im trying to show the image inside a dropify input tag using a pop up custom modal that shows up when i click a button that connected to the values of the data in that particular row. How can i properly set the default image of the dropify field properly and re set it when i decided to click away and click at another button in different rows? This is my current codes :

```
<table>
<thead>
...
</thead>
<tbody>
    <td>...</td>
    <!--the row containing the images -->
    <td>
        <img id="pic" src="url('api/image',['foldername','filename']" style="width:150;height:150"/>
    </td>
    ....
    <!--the row containing the buttons -->
    <td>
        <a href"#" ... data-image="{{$data->image}}" >
        ....
    </td>
</table>
```

The modal to show the image :

```
<div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="pic">Picture:</label>
       <div class="col-sm-10">
            <small>max 650x650</small>
                 <div>
                       <input type="file" id="image_edit" class="form-control" />
                  </div>
                  <p class="errorPicture text-center alert alert-danger hidden"></p>
        </div>
```

The jquery to set the image :

```
$(document).on('click', '.show-modal', function(){
  ...
   var imagePath = $IMAGE_PATH;
   $('#image_edit').attr("data-default-file",imagePath);
   $('#image_edit').dropify();
  ...

}
```

The problem i was having :

- the value default image cannot be retrieved using $(this).data('image');
- the default image doesnt change when i click on another button on different row

How do you properly implement this?

Answer (score 0):

use this `data-default-file="{{ asset($product->image) }}"`, see snippet below:

```html
  <input type="file" id="input-file-now" name="image" class="dropify"  data-default-file="{{ asset($product->image) }}"  />
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
  <input type="file" id="input-file-now" name="image" class="dropify"  data-default-file="{{ asset($product->image) }}"  />
```

Comment: It's important to not just post code, but to also include a description of what the code does and why you are suggesting it. This helps others understand the context and purpose of the code, and makes it more useful for others who may be reading the question or answer. @Fahad Islam.

Comment: for those who are looking for load image with ajax call (or somehow they want to update image on dropify) : stackoverflow.com/a/75844584/4671431